# Get Poetry script endpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-poetry, toml

[Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#run) has a nice way of running your Python entrypoints using `poetry run <entrypoint>`. What would be the best way to programatically get a list of `<entrypoints>` from the `pyproject.toml` with Python or Bash?

For example, the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "random-tool"
version = "1.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
tool = "tool.function:main"
other_tool = "other_tool.function:main"
all_the_tools = "other_tool.function:all"
```

Output being:

```
entrypoint = [ "tool", "other_tool", "all_the_tools" ]
```

Comment: could you update the question to provide more details about the desired output? do you want to print the literal string `entrypoint = [ ... ]`? do you want to assign the literal string `[ ... ]` to the variable `entrypoint` (and if so, are we talking about a python variable or bash variable)? are you looking to assign the 3x strings as separate values to an array named `entrypoint[]`?

Comment: @markp-fuso I suppose I'm talking about having a bash/python variable which I am able to loop over later on, does that help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP has stated in a comment the desire to collect the endpoints into a structure that can be iterated over at a later point.

For this answer I'm going to focus on one `bash/array` idea ...

First issue is to parse desired data from the `pyproject.toml` file; my sample file:

```
$ cat poetry.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "random-tool"
version = "1.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
tool = "tool.function:main"
other_tool = "other_tool.function:main"
all_the_tools = "other_tool.function:all"

[tool.poetry.other_stuff]         # add some gibberish to demonstrate extracting data from middle of file
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
```

One `sed` idea for parsing out the desired data:

```
$ sed -En '1,/\[tool.poetry.scripts\]/d;/^$/,$d;s/^([^ ]+) .*$/\1/p' poetry.toml
tool
other_tool
all_the_tools
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable `E`xtended regex support and suppress printing of pattern space (`n`)
- `1,/\[tool.poetry.scripts\]/d` - deletes everything in the rangefrom line 1 to the line containing the string `[tool.poetry.scripts\]`
- `/^$/,$d` - deletes everything in the range from the first blank line (`^$`) to the end of the file (`$`)
- `s/^([^ ]+) .*$)/\1/p` - define first capture group as start of line up to, but not including, first space (`([^ ]+)`), then print the first capture group (`\1/p`)

One idea using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
/\[tool.poetry.scripts\]/ { extract=1        # set "extract" flag
                            next             # go to next record
                          }

# when "extract" flag = 1:

extract                   { if ( NF == 0)    # if no fields (ie, blank line) then
                               exit          # exit processing
                            print $1         # else print first field
                          }
' poetry.toml
tool
other_tool
all_the_tools
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk '/\[tool.poetry.scripts\]/ { extract=1 ; next } extract { if ( NF == 0) { exit } ; print $1}' poetry.toml
tool
other_tool
all_the_tools
```

---

---

From here there are several ways to get this data loaded into a `bash` array structure; one idea using `mapfile`:

```
# load sed output into array endpoints[]

$ mapfile -t endpoints < <(sed -En '1,/\[tool.poetry.scripts\]/d;/^$/,$d;s/^([^ ]+) .*$/\1/p' poetry.toml)

# display contents of the endpoints[] array

$ typeset -p endpoints
declare -a endpoints=([0]="tool" [1]="other_tool" [2]="all_the_tools")
```

---

---

At this point the data has been loaded into the `endpoints[]` array and can be iterated over at a later point, eg:

```
for i in "${!endpoints[@]}"
do
    echo "endpoints[${i}] = ${endpoints[${i}]}"
done
```

Which generates:

```
endpoints[0] = tool
endpoints[1] = other_tool
endpoints[2] = all_the_tools
```

Answer (score 3):

With python this is quite easy, because you can use [toml](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) to parse the `pyproject.toml` file into a dictionary:

```py
import toml

pyproject = toml.load("pyproject.toml")
print(pyproject["tool"]["poetry"]["scripts"].keys())
```